# Numerical solution for overdetermined, albeit well posed 1st order PDE system

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve for $\theta(u,v)$ defined by the system

\begin{align}
\partial_v h+h\:\partial_u\theta=0\\
\partial_u h-h\:\partial_v\theta=0
\end{align}

being $\log h(u,v)$ a given harmonic function. The condition $(\partial^2_{u}+\partial^2_v)\log h=0$ guarantees that $\partial^2_{uv}\theta=\partial^2_{vu}\theta$, so the system is know to be well defined and its solution exists up to a constant $\theta(u_0,v_0)$. For simple enough $h$, `DSolve` returns the analytic solution, however when moving to `NDSolve` I get the alert of overdetermined system and no answer.

```
 h[u_, v_] := u^2 + v^2
 NDSolveValue[{D[h[u, v], v] + h[u, v]*D[θ[u, v], u] == 0, 
               D[h[u, v], u] - h[u, v]*D[θ[u, v], v] == 0, 
               θ[0, 0] == 0}, θ, {u, 0.1, 1}, {v, 0.1, 1}]
```

Comment: Do you simply want to solve the problem numerically, or want to make `NDSolve` solve it?

Comment: @xzczd Of course one can write an explicit integral solution and then calculate the integrals numerically, but it becomes very inefficient when varying $h$, that's why I want to keep it posed as a differential system and use `NDSolve`.

Comment: I'm afraid it's hard to make use of `NDSolve` for this special problem. But using finite difference method, I can solve for 50*50 grid in about 1 second. Is this solution of interest?

Comment: The problem is not defined well for numerical integration. First, there is no any bound for u, v, h, and $\theta$. What kind of solution we suppose to get in this case?

Comment: @xzczd Any approach would be of great interest for me.

Comment: @AlexTrounev In the simplest case I would set an arbitrary squared domain $(u,v)\in [u_1,v_1]\times [u_2,v_2]$, in general containing the origin but not necessarily; this should not be crucial, I think the problem is that Mathematica  does not recognize the initial condition. (I'm not sure this answers your sub-question)

Comment: @DanielCastro For numerical integration we need numbers, not `u1, v1, u2, v2`. In your example you use `{u, 0.1, 1}, {v, 0.1, 1}` and `\[Theta][0, 0] == 0`. But point `u=0, v=0` is not included in the boundary. It could be better to map this system on polar coordinate $\rho, \phi$ and solve in the range $0\le \phi \le 2 \pi, 0\le \rho \le 1$

Comment: @AlexTrounev I mean $u_1,\:u_2,\:v_1\:v_2$ are given reals, I just want to have a general formulation but of course for a particular example one plugs in numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, let me provide a solution based finite difference method (FDM). The idea is simple (and it's not the first time I use it, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191874/1871) for another example): the system is overdetermined in form, so we use `LeastSquare` to solve it.

I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for generation of difference equation system.

```
h[u_, v_] := u^2 + v^2
sys = {D[h[u, v], v] + h[u, v] D[θ[u, v], u] == 0, 
       D[h[u, v], u] - h[u, v] D[θ[u, v], v] == 0, 
       θ[0, 0] == 0};

points@u = points@v = 50; 
domain@u = domain@v = {0, 1}; 
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {u, v};
difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[θ[u, v], grid /@ {u, v}, difforder];
aesys = {ptoafunc@Most@sys, Last@sys} // Flatten // DeleteCases[True];
vars = Outer[θ, grid@u, grid@v] // Flatten;
{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[aesys, vars];
sollst = LeastSquares[marray, -N@barray]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.712605, Null} *)
solmat = ArrayReshape[sollst, points /@ {u, v}];
sol = ListInterpolation[solmat, grid /@ {u, v}];
Plot3D[sol[u, v], {u, #, #2}, {v, #3, #4}] & @@ Flatten[domain /@ {u, v}]
```

[image]

Let's compare it with the exact solution `-2 ArcTan[u/v]` provided by Alex in the comment below:

```
With[{eps = 10^-3}, 
 Manipulate[
  Plot[{sol[u, v], const - 2 ArcTan[u/v]}, {u, eps, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}], {v, eps, 1}, {{const, 1.5}, 1, 2}]]
```

[image]

### Remark

1. The ratio `points@u/points@v` will influence the solution by a constant. (This isn't a problem, of course. ) This is probably because function value `θ[0, 0]` only exists as a limit in certain direction.
2. You can set the b.c. at other points of the domain e.g. `θ[49/50, 49/50] == 0` for `points@u = points@v = 51`.

Comment: Could you define `sys` as well?

Comment: @alex Oops, I forgot to copy it. Added. Thx for pointing out.

Comment: You are welcome! Is your solution correlate with exact solution `-2 ArcTan[u/v]`?

Comment: @Alex Yeah, see the new-added GIF.

Comment: Now it looks very nice (+1).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative method we can use the Euler wavelets collocation method described in our [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/10/3/165) and on my [page](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2457908). We add one equation $\theta_1=\int{\theta_u du},\theta_2=\int{\theta_v dv}, \theta_1=\theta_2$. With this method we can solve the problem on the grid $16\times 16$ with absolute error of $4\times 10^{-3}$. First, we define exact solution

```
h[u_, v_] := 
 u^2 + v^2; sys = {Derivative[0, 1][h][u, v] + 
    h[u, v] D[\[Theta][u, v], u] == 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0][h][u, v] - h[u, v] D[\[Theta][u, v], v] == 
   0, \[Theta][0, 0] == 0};
DSolveValue[{D[h[u, v], v] + h[u, v]*D[\[Theta][u, v], u] == 0, 
  D[h[u, v], u] - h[u, v]*D[\[Theta][u, v], v] == 0, \[Theta][0, 0] ==
    Pi/2}, \[Theta], {u, v}]


(*Out[]= Function[{u, v}, 1/2 (\[Pi] - 4 ArcTan[u/v])]*)
```

With this exact solution we can test our numerical solution. Second, we compute numerical solution

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t < 
     n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ucol = 
 vcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
M = nn;

U1 = Array[a, {M, M}]; U2 = Array[b, {M, M}]; G1 = 
 Array[g1, {M}]; G2 = Array[g2, {M}];


tet1[u_, v_] := int1[u] . U1 . Psi[v] + G1 . Psi[v]; 
tet2[u_, v_] := Psi[u] . U2 . int1[v] + G2 . Psi[u];
tetv[u_, v_] := Psi[u] . U2 . Psi[v];
tetu[u_, v_] := Psi[u] . U1 . Psi[v];


eq = Join[
   Flatten[Table[
     Derivative[0, 1][h][ucol[[i]], vcol[[j]]] + 
      h[ucol[[i]], vcol[[j]]] tetu[ucol[[i]], vcol[[j]]], {i, M}, {j, 
      M}]], Flatten[
    Table[Derivative[1, 0][h][ucol[[i]], vcol[[j]]] - 
      h[ucol[[i]], vcol[[j]]] tetv[ucol[[i]], vcol[[j]]], {i, M}, {j, 
      M}]], Flatten[
    Table[tet1[ucol[[i]], vcol[[j]]] - tet2[ucol[[i]], vcol[[j]]], {i,
       M}, {j, M}]], {tet1[0, 0], tet2[0, 0]}];

var = Join[Flatten[U1], Flatten[U2], G1, G2];

{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eq, var];



sol = LeastSquares[mat // N, -vec];

rul = Table[var[[i]] -> sol[[i]], {i, Length[var]}];
```

Visualization of numerical and exact solution, and error for $\theta_1, \theta_2$

```
{Plot3D[Evaluate[tet1[u, v] /. rul], {u, .1, 1}, {v, .1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, Exclusions -> None], 
 Plot3D[-2 ArcTan[u/v] + Pi/2, {u, .1, 1}, {v, .1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[Abs[-2 ArcTan[u/v] + Pi/2 - 
    Evaluate[tet1[u, v] /. rul]], {u, .1, 1}, {v, .1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[Abs[-2 ArcTan[u/v] + Pi/2 - 
    Evaluate[tet2[u, v] /. rul]], {u, .1, 1}, {v, .1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 2):

Since it is an overdetermined system this means that one equation is enough to solve it. So you can choose first one or second one:

```
h[u_,v_]:=u^2+v^2
f1=NDSolveValue[{D[h[u,v],v]+h[u,v]*D[\[Theta][u,v],u]==0,\[Theta][0,v]==0},\[Theta],{u,0.1,1},{v,0.1,1}];
f2=NDSolveValue[{D[h[u,v],u]-h[u,v]*D[\[Theta][u,v],v]==0,\[Theta][u,0]==0},\[Theta],{u,0.1,1},{v,0.1,1}];
Plot3D[f1[u,v]+\[Pi]/2,{u,0.1,1},{v,0.1,1}]
Plot3D[f2[u,v]-\[Pi]/2,{u,0.1,1},{v,0.1,1}]
Plot3D[Function[{u,v},1/2 (\[Pi]-4 ArcTan[u/v])][u,v],{u,0.1,1},{v,0.1,1}]
{f1[u,v]+\[Pi]/2,f2[u,v]-\[Pi]/2,Function[{u,v},1/2 (\[Pi]-4 ArcTan[u/v])][u,v]}/.{u->0.2,v->0.3}

(* {0.394725, 0.394815, 0.394791} *)
```

Results `f1` and `f2` differ from exact solution by constants +π/2 and -π/2. If you subtract these constants you get the same result.

Comment: This works for this special case because `θ[u, 0]` and `θ[0, v]` happens to be constant, generally the i.c. in a _line_ is unknown and the other PDE is necessary to determine a solution.

Comment: Either it works or the system has no solution. When we have overdetermined system of equations, then that system has solution only when any subsets of equations of original set of equations which is not overdetermined has solution and all these solutions are the same. So I would say, it works for OP problem not only in this special case but for any other, but then it is necessary to check whether `f1` and `f2` represent the same function.

Comment: No, when i.c. is only given at a *point* the system is not overdetermined.  Just use e.g. `θ[u, 1]==0` for example, the obtained solution is not `-2 ArcTan[u/v]`, but using `θ[1, 1]==0` we can still determine the solution is  `2 ArcTan[1]-2 ArcTan[u/v]`.

Comment: So Mathematica is wrong when it states it is overdetermined?

Comment: `NDSolve` is powerful, but not omnipotent. Probably it's just checking the over-determination in a primary way e.g. comparing the number of equations and variables. Notice `DSolve` can handle this problem properly, as mentioned by OP and shown in Alex's answer.