# Can NDSolve be initialized with a close solution?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, finite-element-method, stiffness

I have a set of 4 first order ODE with 4 initial conditions to be met. It models a simple damped pendulum like the one described [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Scientific_Computing_Simulations_and_Modeling/Scientific_Computing_(Chasnov)/II%3A_Dynamical_Systems_and_Chaos/11%3A_The_Damped%2C_Driven_Pendulum). What changes is the damping term and I switched to first order through Pontryagin's principle. In the model, there is a particular parameter that is making things difficult to solve. It is the parameter called **"`k`"** in the code below. Stiffness seems to increase with its value.

*Ideally*, I would like for `k` to reach up to the value of `10`. However, in my trials, whenever `k > 0.7`, `NDSolve` struggles too much and is not able to further solve the set of ODE successfully.

Therefore, I would like to know if it is possible to initialize `NDSolve` with the solution at `k -> 0.7`, which is successful, as a starting point to search for the solution when `k -> 0.8` (which sould be not to far from the previous solution). This way I could be able to form a loop in order to gradually increase the value of `k`.

Here is the code sample:

```
params = {a -> 0.4, m -> 2.4, Izz -> 1.0, g -> 9.81, fc -> 13.6829};
T = 2.0;
solF = NDSolve[{q'[t] == z[t],
      z'[t] == (-a g m Sin[q[t]] - fc Tanh[k z[t]] + x[t])/(
       Izz + a^2 m),
      p'[t] == (a g m Cos[q[t]] x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m),
      x'[t] == -p[t] + (fc k Sech[k z[t]]^2 x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m),
      q[0.] == 0.,
      z[0.] == 0.,
      q[T] == 0.8,
      z[T] == 0.} /. params /. k -> 0.7,
   {q, z, p, x},
   {t, 0, T},
   Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}
   ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Can this be accomplished?

**EDIT 1**

I have modified the above code according to the first suggestion in the comments. However, the proposed solution does not work for this particular example because it is only 4 additional initial conditions. I first solved the system with the previous code above to obtain a successful solution for `k -> 0.6`. I then assign that solution to  `oldSolF` in order to start the new algorithm.

```
oldSolF = solF; (*obtained with the previous code with k->0.6*)
vars = {q, z, p, x};
varsF[t_] = Through[vars[t]];
params = {a -> 0.4, m -> 2.4, Izz -> 1.0, g -> 9.81, fc -> 13.6829};
T = 2.0;
solF = NDSolve[{q'[t] == z[t],
      z'[t] == (-a g m Sin[q[t]] - fc Tanh[k z[t]] + x[t])/(
       Izz + a^2 m),
      p'[t] == (a g m Cos[q[t]] x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m),
      x'[t] == -p[t] + (fc k Sech[k z[t]]^2 x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m),
      q[0.] == 0.,
      z[0.] == 0.,
      q[T] == 0.8,
      z[T] == 0.} /. params /. k -> 0.7,
   {q, z, p, x},
   {t, 0, T},
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
      Thread[varsF[0] == (varsF[0] /. oldSolF[[2, 1]])]}
   ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

However, at the end I get two error messages indicating that `NDSolve` failed to solve the system:

```
FindRoot: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

NDSolve: The scaled boundary value residual error of 4.2168606782853276`*^7 \
indicates that the boundary values are not satisfied to specified \
tolerances. Returning the best solution found.
```

Any suggestions?

**COMMENT**

I believe that @bbgodfrey contribution answers the initial question most straighforwardly: it uses standard Mathematica functions (makes use of the `InitialSeeding` option from `NDSolve`). However, it should be highlighted that @AlexTrounev and @xzczd solutions are more robust and allow for a higher value of the `k` parameter.

Comment: Something like `vars = {q, z, p, x};
varsF[t_] =  Through[vars[t]];` and  `Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> Thread[varsF[0] == (varsF[0] /. oldsolF[[1]])]}` after saving a successful `solF` as `oldsolF = solF`.

Comment: This problem can be solved with the local discontinuous Galerkin method (LDG) in the range $0.7\le k\le 3.6$. At `k=3.7` we have same message from `FindRoot` as above. Substituting data back in `NDSolve` we can see that `NDSolve` reproduces LDG solution up to `k=1.5`, and over `k=1.5 the  solution deviates from LDG.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Is the LDG method an option in `NDSolve`? I cannot find it in the documentation... Would you share your code? I think that already going up to `k=3.6` is a very good performance increase.

Comment: @Meclassic Actually LDG method is not an option in `NDSolve`. It is not even mentioned in Mathematica while it widely use as an effective solver in combination with FEM for ODEs and PDEs.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I got confused when you mentioned `FindRoot` with LDG. However, I understand that you coded that into Mathematica. Any chance that you could post your code as an alternative answer?

Comment: @Meclassic Please, see my answer.

Comment: I am interested in what these equations describe, what mechanical phenomenon. Provide a link to this phenomenon?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk It is a simple damped pendulum like the one described here: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Scientific_Computing_Simulations_and_Modeling/Scientific_Computing_(Chasnov)/II%3A_Dynamical_Systems_and_Chaos/11%3A_The_Damped%2C_Driven_Pendulum. What changes is the damping term and I switched to first order through Pontryagin's principle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This interesting problem can be solved, at least up to `k = 4.6`, using standard Mathematica functions.  To begin, turn off two extraneous warning messages for convenience.

```
Off[NDSolveValue::femibcnd]
Off[NDSolve`FEM`InitializePDECoefficients::femcscd]
```

Then use the `NDSolve` finite element option with `InitialSeeding` to obtain a solution for `k = 1`.

```
params = {a -> 0.4, m -> 2.4, Izz -> 1.0, g -> 9.81, fc -> 13.6829};
T = 2.0;
{q0[t], z0[t], p0[t], x0[t]} = 
NDSolveValue[{q'[t] == z[t], 
  z'[t] == (-a g m Sin[q[t]] - fc Tanh[k z[t]] + x[t])/(Izz + 
      a^2 m), p'[t] == (a g m Cos[q[t]] x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
  x'[t] == -p[t] + (fc k Sech[k z[t]]^2 x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
  DirichletCondition[{q[t] == 0, z[t] == 0}, t == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[{q[t] == 0.8, z[t] == 0}, t == T]} /. 
  params /. k -> 1, {q[t], z[t], p[t], x[t]}, {t} \[Element] 
  Line[{{0}, {T}}], 
  InitialSeeding -> {q[t] == 0.8 t/T, z[t] == 0, p[t] == 0, x[t] == 0},
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}];
  Join[%[[1 ;; 2]] /. t -> 0, %[[1 ;; 2]] /. t -> T]

(* {0., 0., 0.8, 0.} *)

GraphicsGrid[
    {{Plot[%%[[1]], {t, 0, T}, AxesLabel -> q, 
          LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> All], 
      Plot[%%[[2]], {t, 0, T}, AxesLabel -> z, 
           LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> All]}, 
     {Plot[%%[[3]], {t, 0, T}, AxesLabel -> p, 
            LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> All], 
      Plot[%%[[4]], {t, 0, T}, AxesLabel -> x, 
            LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> All]}}]
```

[image]

For larger values of `k`, use `InitialSeeding` based on the `k = 1` solution just obtained.  Specifically,

```
InitialSeeding -> {q[t] == q0[t] 3/4 + .2 t/T, z[t] == z0[t] 3/4, 
    p[t] == p0[t] 3/4, x[t] == x0[t]/2}
```

Now, we might expect to use `{q[t] == q0[t], z[t] == z0[t], p[t] == p0[t], x[t] == x0[t]}`, but for some unknown reason it does not work at all well.  With the choice above, `k` up to `3.8` can be solved with the result,

[image]

Then, using the solution for `k = 3.8`, we can obtain results up to `k = 4.6`.

```
InitialSeeding -> {q[t] == q00[t] 3/4 + .2 t/T, z[t] == z00[t] 3/4, 
    p[t] == p00[t] 3/4, x[t] == x00[t]/3}
```

[image]

I have been unsuccessful so far in obtaining solutions for larger `k`.

Comment: I did not know about the `InitialSeeding` option and it is what I was looking for from the beginning. However, could you comment as to why you scale down the previous solutions by `3/4` for example and particularly, why use `q[t] == q0[t] 3/4 + .2 t/T`. Are these arbitrary choices in order to ensure `NDSolve` success? Or are these factors specifically chosen for some reason? Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Meclassic These arbitrary choices in order to ensure NDSolve success.  I plan to look at this situation further over the weekend.  `InitialSeeding` is a fairly new option.

Comment: See also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199313/18437)

Comment: Another idea: in the hyperplastic solid mechanics tutorial is a section on solving extremely non liner problems. A second alternative shown there is the method of using a pseudo time integration.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Very nice solution (+1). Probably we need `Do` loop to update `InitialSeeding` same as I do it with  `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 10):

Let consider the local discontinuous Galerkin method in application to solve system of ODEs. The theory is discussed [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036142901384162). The implementation is very straightforward. In this example we use Euler polynomials and Gauss formula for integration

```
params = {a -> 0.4, m -> 2.4, Izz -> 1.0, g -> 9.81, fc -> 13.6829};
T = 2.0; kmax = 30;


Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
UT[mm_, t_] := EulerE[mm, t];

M0 = 5; nn = 12; ns = 4; np = 5; tmax = 2; 
y[t_] = Table[Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, 1, ns}];
eqs = {q'[t] == z[t], 
  z'[t] == (-a g m Sin[q[t]] - fc Tanh[k z[t]] + x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
  p'[t] == (a g m Cos[q[t]] x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
  x'[t] == -p[t] + (fc k Sech[k z[t]]^2 x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m)}; F = 
 Table[eqs[[i, 2]], {i, ns}]; var = {q[t], z[t], p[t], 
  x[t]}; ini = {0, 0, pb, xb}; bc2 = {8/10, 0}; ff = 
 Table[F /. Table[var[[i]] -> y[t][[i]], {i, ns}] /. 
    params /. {k -> (7 + kap)/10}, {kap, 0, kmax}]; 
LDGODEs[M0_, nn_, ns_, np_, f_, ini_, tmax_, kap_] := 
 Module[{dx = tmax/nn,   A = Array[aa, {M0 + 1, nn, ns}]}, 
  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; 
  psi[mm_, k_, t_] := 
   Piecewise[{{UT[
       mm, (2 t - xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])/(xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])], 
      xl[[k]] <= t <= xl[[k + 1]]}, {0, True}}];
  gg = Table[
    GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, xl[[i]], xl[[i + 1]]], {i, nn}];
  dp = Table[
    D[UT[mm, (2 t - xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])/(xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])], 
     t], {k, nn}];
  rul = Table[
    y[t][[i]] -> 
     Sum[aa[mm, k, i] psi[mm - 1, k, t], {mm, 1, M0 + 1}, {k, 1, 
       nn}], {i, ns}];
  eq = Flatten[
    Table[-Sum[
         aa[i + 1, n, 
           ks] (Table[(psi[i, n, t] If[j == 0, 0, 
                dp[[n]] /. mm -> j]), {t, gg[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . 
            gg[[n]][[All, 2]]), {i, 0, 
          M0}] - (Table[(f[[ks]] /. rul) psi[j, n, t], {t, 
           gg[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . gg[[n]][[All, 2]]), {j, 0, M0}, {n, 
       1, nn}, {ks, ns}] + 
     Table[Sum[
        aa[i + 1, n, 
          ks] (psi[i, n, xl[[n + 1]]] psi[j, n, xl[[n + 1]]]), {i, 0, 
         M0}] - Sum[
        If[n < 2, ini[[ks]]/(M0 + 1), 
          aa[i + 1, n - 1, ks] psi[i, n - 1, xl[[n]]]] psi[j, n, 
          xl[[n]]], {i, 0, M0}], {j, 0, M0}, {n, 1, nn}, {ks, ns}]];
  bc = Table[
    Sum[aa[i + 1, k, s] psi[i, k, 2], {i, 0, M0}, {k, nn}] == 
     bc2[[s]], {s, 1, 2}];
  eqn = Table[eq[[k]] == 0, {k, Length[eq]}];
  var = Join[Flatten[A], {pb, xb}]; 
  soln = FindRoot[Join[eqn, bc], 
    Table[{var[[i]], If[kap == 0, 1/10, var[[i]] /. soln]}, {i, 
      Length[var]}]];
  soln];
```

Solution

```
Do[
  ldgsol[kap] = 
    LDGODEs[M0, nn, ns, np, ff[[kap + 1]], ini, tmax, kap];, {kap, 0, 
   kmax}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

In the end we have one message from `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
```

It means that step with `k=3.7` is a limit of this code with current parameters. Visualization

```
leg = {"q", "z", "p", "x"};

Table[Plot[
  Evaluate[
   Table[Sum[aa[i + 1, k, s] psi[i, k, t], {i, 0, M0}, {k, nn}] /. 
     ldgsol[kap], {kap, 0, kmax, 1}]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All,
   PlotLegends -> Table[(7. + n)/10, {n, 0, kmax, 1}], Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> leg[[s]]], {s, ns}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Using this solution we can generate initial data for `NDSolve` and generate new solution

```
data = Table[{.7 + kk/10, pb, xb} /. ldgsol[kk], {kk, 0, kmax, 1}];
sol1 = Table[
   NDSolveValue[{q'[t] == z[t], 
       z'[t] == (-a g m Sin[q[t]] - fc Tanh[k z[t]] + x[t])/(Izz + 
           a^2 m), p'[t] == (a g m Cos[q[t]] x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
       x'[t] == -p[t] + (fc k Sech[k z[t]]^2 x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
       q[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, p[0] == data[[i, 2]], 
       x[0] == data[[i, 3]]} /. params /. k -> data[[i, 1]], {q, z, p,
      x}, {t, 0, T}], {i, Length[data]}];
```

Finally we compare LDG numerical solution BVP and `NDSolve` solution with initial data only

```
Table[{.7 + i/10, 
  Table[Show[
    Plot[sol1[[i + 1]][[s]][t], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All], 
    Plot[Evaluate[
      Sum[aa[i + 1, k, s] psi[i, k, t], {i, 0, M0}, {k, nn}] /. 
       ldgsol[i]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]], {s, ns}]}, {i, 0, kmax}]
```

Please note, that up to `k=1.5` we have a good coincidence `sol1` with `ldgsol`, but then solutions diverge, for example for `k<1.5`
[image: Figure 2]
and for `k>1.5`
[image: Figure 3]

Update 1. With option  `Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}` for `FindRoot` we can extend solution to `k=10.7`, but there are oscillation around some points.
[image: Figure 4]

Code for this case

```
params = {a -> 0.4, m -> 2.4, Izz -> 1.0, g -> 9.81, fc -> 13.6829};
T = 2.0; kmax = 50;


Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
UT[mm_, t_] := EulerE[mm, t];

M0 = 5; nn = 12; ns = 4; np = 5; tmax = 2; 
y[t_] = Table[Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, 1, ns}];
eqs = {q'[t] == z[t], 
  z'[t] == (-a g m Sin[q[t]] - fc Tanh[k z[t]] + x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
  p'[t] == (a g m Cos[q[t]] x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
  x'[t] == -p[t] + (fc k Sech[k z[t]]^2 x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m)}; F = 
 Table[eqs[[i, 2]], {i, ns}]; var = {q[t], z[t], p[t], 
  x[t]}; ini = {0, 0, pb, xb}; bc2 = {8/10, 0}; ff = 
 Table[F /. Table[var[[i]] -> y[t][[i]], {i, ns}] /. 
    params /. {k -> (7 + 2 kap)/10}, {kap, 0, kmax}]; 
LDGODEs[M0_, nn_, ns_, np_, f_, ini_, tmax_, kap_] := 
 Module[{dx = tmax/nn,   A = Array[aa, {M0 + 1, nn, ns}]}, 
  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; 
  psi[mm_, k_, t_] := 
   Piecewise[{{UT[
       mm, (2 t - xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])/(xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])], 
      xl[[k]] <= t <= xl[[k + 1]]}, {0, True}}];
  gg = Table[
    GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, xl[[i]], xl[[i + 1]]], {i, nn}];
  dp = Table[
    D[UT[mm, (2 t - xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])/(xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])], 
     t], {k, nn}];
  rul = Table[
    y[t][[i]] -> 
     Sum[aa[mm, k, i] psi[mm - 1, k, t], {mm, 1, M0 + 1}, {k, 1, 
       nn}], {i, ns}];
  eq = Flatten[
    Table[-Sum[
         aa[i + 1, n, 
           ks] (Table[(psi[i, n, t] If[j == 0, 0, 
                dp[[n]] /. mm -> j]), {t, gg[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . 
            gg[[n]][[All, 2]]), {i, 0, 
          M0}] - (Table[(f[[ks]] /. rul) psi[j, n, t], {t, 
           gg[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . gg[[n]][[All, 2]]), {j, 0, M0}, {n, 
       1, nn}, {ks, ns}] + 
     Table[Sum[
        aa[i + 1, n, 
          ks] (psi[i, n, xl[[n + 1]]] psi[j, n, xl[[n + 1]]]), {i, 0, 
         M0}] - Sum[
        If[n < 2, ini[[ks]]/(M0 + 1), 
          aa[i + 1, n - 1, ks] psi[i, n - 1, xl[[n]]]] psi[j, n, 
          xl[[n]]], {i, 0, M0}], {j, 0, M0}, {n, 1, nn}, {ks, ns}]];
  bc = Table[
    Sum[aa[i + 1, k, s] psi[i, k, 2], {i, 0, M0}, {k, nn}] == 
     bc2[[s]], {s, 1, 2}];
  eqn = Table[eq[[k]] == 0, {k, Length[eq]}];
  var = Join[Flatten[A], {pb, xb}]; 
  soln = FindRoot[Join[eqn, bc], 
    Table[{var[[i]], If[kap == 0, 1/10, var[[i]] /. soln]}, {i, 
      Length[var]}], 
    Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}];
  soln];

Do[
  ldgsol[kap] = 
    LDGODEs[M0, nn, ns, np, ff[[kap + 1]], ini, tmax, kap];, {kap, 0, 
   kmax}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Visualization

```
leg = {"q", "z", "p", "x"};

Table[Plot[
  Evaluate[
   Table[Sum[aa[i + 1, k, s] psi[i, k, t], {i, 0, M0}, {k, nn}] /. 
     ldgsol[kap], {kap, 0, kmax, 1}]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All,
   PlotLegends -> Table[(7. + 2 n)/10, {n, 0, kmax, 1}], 
  Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> leg[[s]]], {s, ns}]
```

Comment: Perhaps try the [Affine Covariant Newton Method](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/affine-covariant-newton.html)

Comment: @user21 Yes, you are right, with option `Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}` we can compute solution up to `k=10`, but `x` has oscillation in some points at `k>4.5`. Probably it is why solution with FEM proposed by bbgodfrey has a bound  $k\le 4.6$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I see that you updated your answer by adding the solutions given by the Affine Covariant Newton method. Could you post the code for the record?

Comment: @Meclassic Yes, code has been added.

Answer (score 6):

It's well-known the default `"Shooting"` method often doesn't work well for nonlinear BVP of ODE, and I'm tired of looking for proper initial guess of initial conditions for shooting method, so let me solve it with finite difference method (FDM).

First of all, it's easy to notice that `z[t]`, `x[t]`, `p[t]` can be easily eliminated, and further analysis suggests the original first order system seems to be troublesome. (To be more specific, it results in singular Jacobian in `FindRoot`). So let's simplify the ODE system to one ODE:

```
params = {a -> 0.4, m -> 2.4, Izz -> 1.0, g -> 9.81, fc -> 13.6829};
T = 2; (* Necessary change *)
Clear[z, x, p]
{z[t_], x[t_], p[t_]} = 
 Solve[##][[1, 1, -1]] & @@@ 
  Thread[{{q'[t] == z[t], 
           z'[t] == (-a g m Sin[q[t]] - fc Tanh[k z[t]] + x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
           x'[t] == -p[t] + (fc k Sech[k z[t]]^2 x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m)}, 
          {z[t], x[t], p[t]}}]

newsys = {p'[t] == (a g m Cos[q[t]] x[t])/(Izz + a^2 m), 
          q[0] == 0., z[0] == 0., q[T] == 0.8, z[T] == 0.} // Simplify
```

Next step is to generate the difference equation system, I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the task:

```
points = 200; difforder = 4; grid = Array[# &, points, {0, T}];
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)    
ptoafunc = pdetoae[q[t], grid, difforder];

aesys = {#[[3 ;; -3]] &@ptoafunc[newsys[[1]]], 
         ptoafunc@newsys[[2 ;;]]} /. params // Flatten;
```

Then let's solve. For nonlinear FDM, we still need an initial guess, but proper initial guess for FDM is generally easier to find than that of shooting method (according to my limited experience). In your case, for `k == 0.5`, a naive guess is enough:

```
guess[t_] = 0;
sollst0 = FindRoot[aesys /. k -> 0.5 // Rationalize[#, 0] &, 
                   Table[{q[t], guess[t]}, {t, grid}], 
                   MaxIterations -> 500, WorkingPrecision -> 16][[All, -1]];
```

`WorkingPrecision` option can actually be taken away to speed up the code. You'll see `FindRoot` spit out warning `FindRoot::lstol` then, but this leads to no observable change in the solution.

Then we use this solution as the new guess:

```
Dynamic[kvalue]

sollstlst = 
   FoldList[FindRoot[aesys /. k -> (kvalue = #2) // Rationalize[#, 0] &, 
                     Transpose[{q /@ grid, #}], 
                     WorkingPrecision -> 16][[All, -1]] &, 
            sollst0, 
            Range[0.6, 10, 0.1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {96.1869, Null} *)
```

Visualization:

```
ListLinePlot[sollstlst[[;; ;; 5]], DataRange -> {0, T}, 
             PlotLegends -> Range[0.5, 10, 0.1][[;; ;; 5]]]
```

[image]

BTW, the last 50 solutions are virtually the same, so perhaps you don't need that large `k`:

```
ListLinePlot[sollstlst[[-50 ;; -1]], DataRange -> {0, T}]
```

[image]

The left work is to obtain `z[t]`, `x[t]` and `p[t]`. This is harder than I thought: I have to use a very dense grid to surpress the non-physical oscillation of derivative (perhaps techniques like WENO will help in this case, but currently there's no built-in support for them):

```
qsol = 
 ListInterpolation[sollstlst[[-1]], grid, InterpolationOrder -> difforder];

pointsfinal = 10^4; gridfinal = Array[# &, pointsfinal, {0, T}];
ptoafuncfinal = pdetoae[q[t], gridfinal, difforder];

aesysfinal = {#[[3 ;; -3]] &@ptoafuncfinal[newsys[[1]]], 
     ptoafuncfinal@newsys[[2 ;;]]} /. params // Flatten;

sollstfinal = 
   FindRoot[aesysfinal /. k -> 10, 
     Table[{q[t], qsol[t]}, {t, gridfinal}]][[All, -1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {20.7576, Null} *)

qsolfinal = 
 ListInterpolation[sollstfinal, gridfinal, InterpolationOrder -> difforder]; 

MapThread[Plot[#[t] /. q -> qsolfinal /. k -> 10 /. params // 
       Evaluate, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> #2] &, {#, 
     ToString /@ #}] &@{q, z, p, x} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

In the final step I choose to live with the `FindRoot::lstol` warning, because otherwise the calculation is too slow.

Comment: I find your solution outstanding. However, I tried to follow your code but I am having issues after the lines `guess[t_] = 0; sollst0 = FindRoot[aesys /. k -> 0.5...`. I have 2 errors: `FindRoot: "The function value {0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<190>>} is not a \
list of numbers with dimensions {200} at"...` and `FindRoot: Search specification 500 should be a list with 1 to 5 elements.`. I imported all the necessary code related to your `pdetoae` function from the link. Any pointers?

Comment: @Meclassic Oops, I forgot I've modified `T` to `T=2`. Without this, the variable names won't match. (After `Rationalize[……, 0]&`, terms like `q[0.]`, `q[0.010050251256281407\`]` become `q[0]`, `q[2/199]`. )

Comment: @xzczd It is nice solution (+1). I always trust in `pdetoae`, but try to test new method LDG.

Comment: @xzczd I am amazed by the robustness on your code. I can reach up to `k->18.3` as it is, and when I use 400 points, it reaches up to `k->39.1`. Did you publish this method in a journal or something of the sort?

Comment: @Meclassic Nope, I haven't, you see, `pdetoae` is essentially an automation of the built-in ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative`` :) . If you want to cite the code, you may directly cite this web page. (There's a related discussion in meta: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/968/1871 )

Comment: @xzczd "`pdetoae` is essentially an automation of the built-in..." That may be the case, but I still find it interesting that your code outperforms most native Mathematica solutions.

Comment: @xzczd Out of curiosity, you say: "So let's simplify the ODE system to one ODE". Is there a mathematical (or technical) reason for solving 1 fourth order equation instead of the original 4 first order equations? Does your code not work as-is with the original system? I ask this because I always thought that first-order systems were generally easier to solve (is it not the case?).

Comment: @Meclassic As mentioned in the answer, "further analysis suggests the original first order system seems to be troublesome (To be more specific, it results in singular Jacobian in FindRoot)" This is the reason I eliminated the system to one ODE. I noticed this mainly by trial and error, so sadly I don't have a in-depth mathematical explanation for it. "I always thought that first-order systems were generally easier to solve." According to my (limited) experience, there's no such rule.