# Cannot get a ParametricPlot from NDSolve and NIntegrate solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am numerically solving this ODE, and I do get a solution. I then need to use this solution to find derivatives and integrals of it, so I define functions using this solution. But when I try to obtain a parametric plot, I do not get a result. I am sure that the problem is with the part that I am Nintegrating but I do not understand the reason because I am able to plot that separately.

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{1 - Derivative[1][r][t]^2 - r[t]*Derivative[2][r][t] - r[t]*(1 - Derivative[1][r][t]^2)^(1/2) == 0, Derivative[1][r][0] == 1, Derivative[1][r][1] == 0}, r, {t, 0, 1}]
func[t_] := r[t] /. First[sol2]
func1[u_] := (D[r[t] /. sol2, t] /. t -> u)^2
ParametricPlot[{func[t] /. t -> u, NIntegrate[(1 - func1[y])^(1/2), {y, 0, u}]}, {u, 0, 1}]
```

Here's the result that I get when I plot that part separately:

```
Plot[NIntegrate[(1 - func1[y])^(1/2), {y, 0, u}], {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am not getting the plot for the second part of your question as well. You have not defined `sol2`.

Comment: @codebpr I just added that definition as well.

Comment: To regularize solution, we need some restriction for `r[t]`. Is function `r[t]` positive or negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `NumericQ` to evaluate integral as follows

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{1 - Derivative[1][r][t]^2 - r[t]*Derivative[2][r][t] -
       r[t]*(1 - Derivative[1][r][t]^2)^(1/2) == 0, 
    Derivative[1][r][0] == 1, Derivative[1][r][1] == 0}, r, {t, 0, 1}];
func[t_] := r[t] /. First[sol2];
func1[u_] := (D[r[t], t] /. sol2[[1]] /. t -> u)^2;
g[u_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(1 - func1[y])^(1/2), {y, 0, u}];

ParametricPlot[{func[t] /. t -> u, g[u]}, {u, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 8], AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Note, that BVP solution with Neuman boundary condition on two ends computed with `NDSolve` up to arbitrary constant of about $4.70033\times 10^9$ in this case. If you need `func[t]` of about 1, then BVP could be regularized like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191476/poisson-equation-with-pure-neumann-boundary-conditions/271682?noredirect=1#comment680090_271682).

Comment: I had worked on this problem and noticed the solution does not satisfy the boundary conditions:  When taking the derivative of the solution via funcD[t_]=D[func[t],t], then funcD[0]=0.873  and funcD[1]=0.061 and increasing WorkingPrecision did not improve the results.

Comment: @josh Yes, it is why constant $4.70033\times 10^9$ so big.