# Numerical solution of a partial derivative problem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

**WARNING**: a couple of days ago I posted a similar question, but due to the impossibility of `DirichletCondition[]` to handle "cross-coupling of dependent variables" I thought of reformulating the same problem using a single function.

---

The goal is to find a function $f : \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta f = 0 & \text{on} \; \Omega \\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} n} f = y\,n_x - x\,n_y & \text{on} \; \partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$

with $n = (n_x,\,n_y)$ exterior normal vector to $\partial\Omega$.

Therefore, once the following plane region is defined:

```
c[x_, y_] := 2 x^2 + 3 y^2
{nx, ny} = Grad[c[x, y], {x, y}];

Ω = ImplicitRegion[c[x, y] <= 1, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[Ω, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I tried to set the problem by writing:

```
bcs = NeumannValue[y nx - x ny, True];
fsol = NDSolveValue[Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}] == bcs, f, {x, y} ∈ Ω];
Plot3D[fsol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

but unfortunately I got tons of warnings:

> NDSolveValue::femibcnd: No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue was specified for {f}; the result may not be unique.

> LinearSolve::parpiv: Zero pivot was detected during the numerical factorization or there was a problem in the iterative refinement process. It is possible that the matrix is ill-conditioned or singular.

> NDSolveValue::fempsf: PDESolve could not find a solution.

and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Ideas? Thank you!

---

**EDIT 1:** copying the [code of user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191802/32491) I wrote the following routine:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
DiniNeumann[f_, Ω_] := Module[
  {dpde, dbc, vd, sd, mdata, g, load, stiffness, damping, mass, 
   prec, dof, loadContribution, stiffnessContribution, initCoeffs, 
   constraintMatrix, constraintRows, constraintValueMatrix},
  {dpde, dbc, vd, sd, mdata} = Quiet[ProcessPDEEquations[
     {Laplacian[g[x, y], {x, y}] == NeumannValue[f, True]}, g, 
     {x, y} ∈ Ω]]; {load, stiffness, damping, mass} = dpde["All"];
  DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness}, dbc];
  prec = mdata["Precision"]; dof = mdata["DegreesOfFreedom"];
  loadContribution = SparseArray[{}, {dof, 1}, N[0, prec]];
  stiffnessContribution = SparseArray[{}, {dof, dof}, N[0, prec]];
  initCoeffs = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
    "LoadCoefficients" -> {{1}}]; 
  constraintMatrix = Transpose[DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, mdata, 
    sd]["LoadVector"]]; constraintRows = {1}; 
  constraintValueMatrix = SparseArray[{{N[0, prec]}}];
  dbc = DiscretizedBoundaryConditionData[{loadContribution, 
    stiffnessContribution, constraintMatrix, constraintRows, 
    constraintValueMatrix, {dof, 0, Length[constraintRows]}}, 1];
  DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness}, dbc, 
   "ConstraintMethod" -> "Append"]; ElementMeshInterpolation[{Ω}, 
   Take[LinearSolve[stiffness, load], mdata["DegreesOfFreedom"]]]]
```

thanks to which it's sufficient to write:

```
Ω = ToElementMesh@ImplicitRegion[2 x^2 + 3 y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];
f = DiniNeumann[y (4 x) - x (6 y), Ω];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

to get what you want:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2:** thanks to suggestions from *Ulrich Neumann* and *user21*, writing:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

Ω = ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[2 x^2 + 3 y^2 <= 1, {x, y}], 
                  "IncludePoints" -> {{0, 0}}];

fsol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}] == NeumannValue[y (4 x) - x (6 y), 
                     True], DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0]}, 
                     f, {x, y} ∈ Ω];

Plot3D[fsol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

I get:

[image]

which apparently is lower quality than what you got above (at least using the version `13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (August 14, 2022)`).

---

**EDIT 3:** in version `13.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)` the plot is smooth, all fixed!

Comment: Pure Neumann b.c. is a bit troublesome: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191476/1871

Comment: @TeM Please show your solutione, thanks.

Comment: You don't need partial derivatives. The @user21`s  solution(thanks for adding)   and my solution are the same(up to a constant)

Comment: @TeM If your larger problem is still a pure NeumannProblem, adding a DirichletCondition should work too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution of this Laplaceproblem is unique except for a constant. That's  why it's necessary to add a Dirichletcondition(Don't know why it isn't sufficient to add bc of an inner point `f[0,0]==0`):

```
c[x_, y_] := 2 x^2 + 3 y^2
{nx, ny} = Grad[c[x, y], {x, y}];

\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[c[x, y] <= 1, {x, y}];
```

For Dirichletcondition we need to know one boundary point

```
xyRand = MeshCoordinates[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[\[CapitalOmega]]];(* some boundary points*)

bcs = NeumannValue[y nx - x ny, True] 
fsol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}] == NeumannValue[ -2 x y, True] , 
DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0,x == xyRand[[1, 1]] && y == xyRand[[1, 2]]]}, 
f, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega] ] 
Plot3D[fsol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141169/discussion-on-answer-by-ulrich-neumann-numerical-solution-of-a-partial-derivativ).