# On the Dirichlet integral

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

Continuing [this topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/276844/32491), once the *Dini-Neumann problem* is solved:

$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta f = 0 & \text{on} \; \Omega \\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} n} f = y\,n_x - x\,n_y & \text{on} \; \partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$

with $n = (n_x,\,n_y)$ exterior normal vector to $\partial\Omega$, the goal is the calculation of:

$$
\color{blue}{J \equiv \iint_{\Omega} \left(f_x\,y - f_y\,x\right)\text{d}x\,\text{d}y}\,.
$$

On the other hand, we also have:

$$
J = \iint_{\Omega} \left[\left(f\,y\right)_x - \left(f\,x\right)_y\right]\text{d}x\,\text{d}y
$$

which by the *divergence theorem* is equivalent to:

$$
J = \int_{\partial\Omega} f\left(y\,n_x - x\,n_y\right)\text{d}s
$$

and for the *boundary condition*:

$$
J = \int_{\partial\Omega} f\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}n}f\right)\text{d}s = \int_{\partial\Omega} \left(f\,f_x\,n_x + f\,f_y\,n_y\right)\text{d}s\,.
$$

This done, again by the *divergence theorem*:

$$
J = \iint_{\Omega} \left[(f\,f_x)_x + (f\,f_y)_y\right]\text{d}x\,\text{d}y = \iint_{\Omega} \left(f_x^2 + f_y^2 + f\,\Delta f\right)\text{d}x\,\text{d}y
$$

that is, since $f$ is an *harmonic function* on $\Omega$:

$$
\color{\red}{J = \iint_{\Omega} \left(f_x^2 + f_y^2\right)\text{d}x\,\text{d}y}\,,
$$

known in the literature as the [Dirichlet integral](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral).

---

Therefore, after determining the *harmonic function*:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

Ω = ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[x^4 + y^4 <= 1, {x, y}], "IncludePoints" -> {{0, 0}}];

f = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[g[x, y], {x, y}] == NeumannValue[y (4 x^3) - x (4 y^3), True], 
                  DirichletCondition[g[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0]}, g, {x, y} ∈ Ω];
```

and verified that it's accurate enough:

```
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
NIntegrate[Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

> -0.00000293157

> 0.00292529

I tried to calculate the *Dirichlet integral* in its two equivalent versions:

```
NIntegrate[D[f[x, y], x] y - D[f[x, y], y] x, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
NIntegrate[D[f[x, y], x]^2 + D[f[x, y], y]^2, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

> -0.48313

> 1.84564

but it's evident that something went wrong, but I don't know what! Ideas? Thank you!

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to the precious comment of *xzczd* I understood that:

- $(n_x,n_y)$ must necessarily have **unitary length**;
- before the *Laplace operator* it must absolutely be a **minus sign**.

In fact, writing:

```
c[x_, y_] = x^4 + y^4;
{nx, ny} = Normalize[Grad[c[x, y], {x, y}]];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Ω = ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[c[x, y] <= 1, {x, y}],
                  "IncludePoints" -> {{0, 0}}];

f = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[g[x, y], {x, y}] == NeumannValue[y nx - x ny,
                  True], DirichletCondition[g[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0]},
                  g, {x, y} ∈ Ω];

NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
NIntegrate[Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ Ω]

NIntegrate[D[f[x, y], x] y - D[f[x, y], y] x, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
NIntegrate[D[f[x, y], x]^2 + D[f[x, y], y]^2, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

we get:

> 0.000000504282

> -0.000799624

> 0.126589

> 0.126595

which is *approximately* what I want. The only thing that would remain to understand is whether it were possible to obtain a better approximation of those integrals. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you add a reference for Dirichlet integral? It doesn't seem to belong to those mentioned in wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral

Comment: For divergence theorem, $(n_x,n_y)$ should be unit vector, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make the mesh denser by setting `MaxCellMeasure` option:

```
Ω = 
  ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[c[x, y] <= 1, {x, y}], "IncludePoints" -> {{0, 0}}, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];
```

Then the output of

```
NIntegrate[D[f[x, y], x] y - D[f[x, y], y] x, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
NIntegrate[D[f[x, y], x]^2 + D[f[x, y], y]^2, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

is

> ```
> 0.126603
> 0.126603
> ```