# Symbolic solution for Laplace equation with pure Neumann b.c. and constraint at a point

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Starting problem:

$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla^2 f = 0 & \text{on} \; \Omega \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{n}} f = y\,n_x - x\,n_y & \text{on} \; \partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$

with $\Omega \equiv [-b/2,\,b/2] \times[-h/2,\,h/2]$ and $\mathbf{n} \equiv (n_x,n_y)$ exterior normal vector to $\partial\Omega$.

Writing:

```
{b, h} = {100, 200};
A = ImplicitRegion[{-b/2 <= x <= b/2, -h/2 <= y <= h/2}, {x, y}];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
B = ToElementMesh[A, "IncludePoints" -> {{0, 0}}];

g = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}] ==                           
                  NeumannValue[-y, x == -b/2 && -h/2 <= y <= h/2] +                        
                  NeumannValue[+y, x == +b/2 && -h/2 <= y <= h/2] +                         
                  NeumannValue[+x, y == -h/2 && -b/2 <= x <= b/2] +                          
                  NeumannValue[-x, y == +h/2 && -b/2 <= x <= b/2],                             
                  DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0]},
                 f, {x, y} ∈ B];

Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, y} ∈ B, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

I get:

[image]

which is exactly what I want.

On the other hand, trying to get an exact solution:

```
DSolve[{Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
        Derivative[1, 0][f][-b/2, y] == +y,
        Derivative[1, 0][f][+b/2, y] == -y,
        Derivative[0, 1][f][x, -h/2] == -x,
        Derivative[0, 1][f][x, +h/2] == +x,
        f[0, 0] == 0}, f[x, y], {x, y},
        Assumptions -> {-b/2 <= x <= b/2, -h/2 <= y <= h/2}]
```

it would seem that `13.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)` can't find a *solution in Fourier series*. Is that right, or am I doing it wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The b.c. in your `DSolve` is incorrect, it should be `Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, {Derivative[1, 0][f][-b/2, y] == y, Derivative[1, 0][f][+b/2, y] == y, Derivative[0, 1][f][x, -h/2] == -x, 
 Derivative[0, 1][f][x, +h/2] == -x}`. Correcting this doesn't resolve the issue, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post contains several code blocks, you can copy them easily with the help of [`importCode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/1871).

---

It's well known that, though `DSolve` is improved these years, it's still not strong enough, so let me add a solution based on [`finiteFourierCosTransform`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871).

We first change the variable to make the b.c.s in `x` direction homogeneous:

```
Clear[b, h, g]

With[{f = f[x, y]}, {eq, bc} = 
     {Laplacian[f, {x, y}] == 0, 
      {D[f, x] == y /. x -> -b/2,  D[f, x] == y /. x -> b/2, 
       D[f, y] == -x /. y -> -h/2, D[f, y] == -x /. y -> h/2}}];

solparti = Function[{x, y}, aa x^2 + bb y^2 + cc x y]
(* Function[{x, y}, aa x^2 + bb y^2 + cc x y] *)

{eq, bc[[;; 2]]} /. f -> solparti // Simplify // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates
rule = Solve[%, {aa, bb, cc}][[1]]
(* {aa + bb == 0, aa b + y == cc y, aa b + cc y == y} *)
(* {aa -> 0, bb -> 0, cc -> 1} *)

rulef = f -> ({x, y} |-> Evaluate[g[x, y] + solparti[x, y] /. rule])
(* f -> Function[{x, y}, x y + g[x, y]] *)

{neweq, newbc} = {eq, bc} /. rulef // Simplify
(* {Derivative[0, 2][g][x, y] + Derivative[2, 0][g][x, y] == 
  0, {Derivative[1, 0][g][-(b/2), y] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][g][b/2, y] == 0, 
  2 x + Derivative[0, 1][g][x, -(h/2)] == 0, 2 x + Derivative[0, 1][g][x, h/2] == 0}} *)
```

Then we make the transform. (Definition of `finiteFourierCosTransform` isn't included in this post, please find it in the link above. )

```
Format@finiteFourierCosTransform[a_, __] := ℱ[a]

Assuming[{b > 0}, 
 finiteFourierCosTransform[{neweq, newbc[[3 ;;]]}, {x, -b/2, b/2}, n] /. 
  Rule @@@ newbc[[;; 2]]]
```

[image]

```
tsys = % /. a_finiteFourierCosTransform :> a[[1]]
```

[image]

```
tsol0 = DSolveValue[Simplify[tsys, n == 0], g[x, y], y]

tsol = DSolveValue[Simplify[tsys, n > 0], g[x, y], y]

tsolgeneral = Piecewise[{{tsol, n > 0}}, tsol0]

sol = inverseFiniteFourierCosTransform[tsolgeneral, n, {x, -b/2, b/2}] /. 
  C[1] -> \[ScriptCapitalC]

solfinal = f[x, y] /. rulef /. g[x, y] -> sol /. C -> Infinity
```

[image]

When calculating `tsol0`, there's a `DSolveValue::bvsing` warning. This is expected, because we haven't used the constraint at $(0,0)$. Symbolically calculating `\[ScriptCapitalC]` is too expensive (Frankly speaking, I'm not sure if `Sum` is capable of calculating it. ) So let's simply keep in mind that the `\[ScriptCapitalC]` is a constant that makes the solution be `0` at $(0,0)$.

Check with first 50 terms of the series:

```
tst = solfinal /. Infinity -> 50 /. \[ScriptCapitalC] -> 0 // ReleaseHold;
```

Seems that `\[ScriptCapitalC] == 0`:

```
tst /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
(* 0 *)

Block[{b = 100, h = 200}, 
 Plot3D[tst, {x, -b/2, b/2}, {y, -h/2, h/2}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

### Remark

Actually it's not necessary to make the b.c.s homogeneous. Then we'll obtain the following solution:

```
Assuming[{b > 0}, 
  finiteFourierCosTransform[{eq, bc[[3 ;;]]}, {x, -b/2, b/2}, n] /. 
   Rule @@@ bc[[;; 2]]];
tsys = % /. a_finiteFourierCosTransform :> a[[1]];

tsol0 = DSolveValue[Simplify[tsys, n == 0], f[x, y], y];

tsol = DSolveValue[Simplify[tsys, n > 0], f[x, y], y];

tsolgeneral = Piecewise[{{tsol, n > 0}}, tsol0];

sol = inverseFiniteFourierCosTransform[tsolgeneral, n, {x, -b/2, b/2}] /. 
  C[1] -> \[ScriptCapitalC] /. C -> Infinity
```

[image]

This solution is definitely correct, but a bit confusing, because you'll find the b.c. in `x` direction isn't satisfied!:

```
tst2 = sol /. Infinity -> 50 /. \[ScriptCapitalC] -> 0 // ReleaseHold;
Block[{b = 100, h = 200}, Plot[D[tst2, x] /. x -> b/2 // Evaluate, {y, -h/2, h/2}]]
```

[image]

Why? This is all because of the property of Fourier cosine series. If we stagger the boundary a bit, we'll see a reasonable output:

```
Block[{b = 100, h = 200, approx = 0.9}, 
 Plot[D[tst2, x] /. x -> -b/2 approx // Evaluate, {y, -h/2, h/2}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With analytical, you can't have all BC's be NeumannValue because this gives no unique solution. At least one edge needs to be fixed (i.e. Dirichlet), then `DSolve` can solve it.

Also, I do not understand `DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0` this is condition at point, not on the edge of the square.

Compare solution on square of edge length L

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
L = 1;
pde = Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
bcOnLeftEdge = Derivative[1, 0][f][-L/2, y] == 0
bcOnRightEdge = Derivative[1, 0][f][L/2, y] == 0
bcOnBottomEdge = Derivative[0, 1][f][x, -L/2] == 0
bcOnTopEdge = Derivative[0, 1][f][x, L/2] == 0
bc = {bcOnLeftEdge, bcOnRightEdge, bcOnBottomEdge, bcOnTopEdge}
sol = DSolve[{pde, bc},f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now change one edge (top one) and make it `DirichletCondition` condition, in order for the solution to be unique, then it can solve it.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
L = 1;
pde = Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
bcOnLeftEdge = Derivative[1, 0][f][-L/2, y] == 0
bcOnRightEdge = Derivative[1, 0][f][L/2, y] == 0
bcOnBottomEdge = Derivative[0, 1][f][x, -L/2] == 0
bcOnTopEdge = f[x, L/2] == g[x] (*some arbitrary function*)
bc = {bcOnLeftEdge, bcOnRightEdge, bcOnBottomEdge, bcOnTopEdge}
sol = DSolve[{pde, bc}, f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: OP's problem is a variant of this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191476/1871 See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/276844/1871

Comment: **which as it is formulated has a unique solution up to a constant** sure, I know this, but this still makes it not unique for the purpose of analytical solution and this is why DSolve can not solve it when all edges are Neumann. You can't add condition at one point in the middle for the analytical solution like you did with the numerical, then `DSolve` will no longer solve. Conditions have to be put on the boundary edges only for Laplace pde. (for analytical solving. Numerical is all different game).