How to solve electric drift and diffusion PDE using `NDSolveValue`?
I am trying to learn how to use NDSolveValue with various boundary conditions. After going through several examples here, I thought I'd try it on what I thought would be simple: charge drift and diffusion in the steady state. I am wanting to look at significantly more complicated PDEs but I figure I should start with something more basic first.
I tried to follow the documentation the best I could

and ended up with
(*Define the parameters*)
a = 1; (*Domain size in x direction*)
b = 10; (*Domain size in y direction*)
\[Alpha] = 0.1; (*electric field*)
c = 0.2;(*diffusion constasnt*)
J = 1;

(*Define the PDE with Neumann boundary conditions;
constant current at top and bottom boundaries;
no current at left and right boundaries*)
pde1 = Div[-( {
         {c, 0},
         {0, c}
        } ) . Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}] - \[Alpha] u[x, y] {0, 1}, {x, 
     y}] == NeumannValue[J, y == -b] + NeumannValue[-J, y == b] + 
    NeumannValue[0, x == -a] + NeumannValue[0, x == a];

(*Solve the PDE over the region*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde1}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-a, -b}, {a, b}], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement"}];

(*Plot the solution*)
ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", "u"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Steady-state solution for u"]

which is producing rubbish

For boundary conditions, I've set a current J and -J on the bottom and top using NeumannValue (the - is since current enters region on one boundary and exits on the other); and set current to 0 transverse to wire. As you can see above, I'm getting an error with these boundary conditions.
I'm using Mathematica 13.2.
Update 1:
Using Inactive as suggest in comments below
b = 10; (*Domain size in y direction*)
\[Alpha] = 10.0; (*electric field*)
c = 100;(*diffusion constasnt*)
J = 1;

(*Define the PDE with Neumann boundary conditions;
constant current at top and bottom boundaries;
no current at left and right boundaries*)
pde1 = Inactive[
     Div][-({{c, 0}, {0, c}}) . 
       Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] - \[Alpha] u[x, y] {0, 1}, {x, 
     y}] == NeumannValue[J, y == -b] + NeumannValue[-J, y == b];

(*Solve the PDE over the region*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde1}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-a, -b}, {a, b}], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement"}];

(*Plot the solution*)
ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", "u"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Steady-state solution for u"]

gives

Update 2:
Using Inactive and a Dirichlet b.c. gives
(*Define the parameters*)
a = 1; (*Domain size in x direction*)
b = 10; (*Domain size in y direction*)
\[Alpha] = 10.0; (*electric field*)
c = 100;(*diffusion constasnt*)
J = 1;

(*Define the PDE with Neumann boundary conditions;
constant current at top and bottom boundaries;
no current at left and right boundaries*)
pde1 = Inactive[
     Div][-({{c, 0}, {0, c}}) . 
       Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] - \[Alpha] u[x, y] {0, 1}, {x, 
     y}] == NeumannValue[J, y == -b] + NeumannValue[-J, y == b];

(*Solve the PDE over the region*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde1, u[x, -10] == 1}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-a, -b}, {a, b}], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement"}];

(*Plot the solution*)
ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", "u"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Steady-state solution for u"]

yields


Do you see the blue circle-i at the end of the message? Click on it to get help for this problem.

There are several methods to regularize this problem - see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191476/poisson-equation-with-pure-neumann-boundary-conditions/191518#191518

Try inactive form pde1 = Inactive[      Div][-({{c, 0}, {0, c}}) .         Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] - \[Alpha]  u[x, y]  {0,         1}, {x, y}] ==     NeumannValue[J, y == -b] + NeumannValue[-J, y == b];

@user21 That's something I don't get about NeumannValue or maybe pde b.c.s in general. Is not setting the Neumann b.c. per the documentation actually setting a Robin type b.c.? That's what I seem to be doing with grad(u) - c u = 0. A Neumann b.c. would be just grad(u) = 0.

@AlexTrounev That does give a more reasonable solution. I see that Inactive makes an expression symbolic. Why is that important to do here? I see many examples of using NDSolveValue that do not use Inactive. Using Inactive still flags the same error. If I do set a Dirichlet b.c. (set u[x,-b] to be a value) and using Inactive I do get what I would believe to be the correct result. I'll try to update my post tomorrow to show these.
