NDSolve for non-linear Poisson equation: the case of a pn diode
I am solving the physical problem of a pn diode under no bias voltage. This involves solving a rather 'complicated' non-linear Poisson's equation in 1D
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\partial^2\phi(z)}{\partial z^2}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rho(\phi(z))
\end{equation}
with boundary conditions $\phi'(z_L)=\phi'(z_R)=0$ and $\rho(\phi(z))$ depending on functions e.g.,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a+b\exp{\left(-\frac{E_\pm \pm e\phi(z)}{k_B T}\right)}}
\end{equation}
The thing is, Mathematica seems not to be converging on the solution of the differential equation. I have tried different methods, but none of them solve the issue. As you can see from the image below, the boundary conditions I am imposing are not satisfied.

When that is the case, I obtain an error like the one below

My code is rather big, so I am attaching the link for it on Google Drive, but I am also pasting it here.
(*--------------  constants ------------------------------------*)

el = 1.6/10^19; 
nm = 10^(-9); 
kb = 8.617/10^5; 
hbar = 6.582/10^16; 
c = 2.997*10^8; 
mo = (0.511*10^6)/c^2; 
Ta = 300; 

(*---------------- N side ------------*)

mcT = 0.1*mo; mvT = 0.2*mo; 
ϵcT = 3.4; 
ϵvT = 0; 
EgT = ϵcT - ϵvT; 
ϵ = (15*8.8542)/10^12; 
Ff[n_,δ_]:=2*Sqrt[Pi]*(E^δ/(4 + E^δ))
NcT[μ_,T_,ϕ_]:=(1/(2*Sqrt[Pi]))*((2*mcT*kb*T)/(Pi*hbar^2))^(3/2)*Ff[1/2,-((ϵcT-μ)/(kb*T)) + ϕ/(kb*T)]; 
PvT[μ_,T_, ϕ_] := (1/(2*Sqrt[Pi]))*((2*mvT*kb*T)/(Pi*hbar^2))^(3/2)*Ff[1/2,-((μ-ϵvT)/(kb*T))-ϕ/(kb*T)]; 
ϵimp = 3.3; 
Dimp = 1*10^(19 + 6); 
Nimp[μ_,T_,ϕ_,z_]=Dimp/(E^((μ - ϵimp)/(kb*T) + ϕ/(kb*T)) + 1); 
θT[z_]:=(1 - Tanh[(-(1000/nm))*z])/2; 
ρT[ϕ_,z_,μ_] :=el*(-NcT[μ,Ta,ϕ]+PvT[μ,Ta,ϕ]+Nimp[μ, Ta, ϕ, z])*θT[z]; 

(*---------------- P side ------------*)

mcD = 0.1*mo; mvD = 0.1*mo; 
ϵcD = 3.4; 
ϵvD = 0; 
EgD = ϵcD - ϵvD; 
ϵ = (15*8.8542)/10^12; 
NcD[μ_,T_,ϕ_]:=(1/(2*Sqrt[Pi]))*((2*mcD*kb*T)/(Pi*hbar^2))^(3/2)*Ff[1/2,-((ϵcD - μ)/(kb*T)) + ϕ/(kb*T)]; 
PvD[μ_,T_,ϕ_]:=(1/(2*Sqrt[Pi]))*((2*mvD*kb*T)/(Pi*hbar^2))^(3/2)*Ff[1/2,-((μ-ϵvD)/(kb*T))-ϕ/(kb*T)]; 
ϵacc = 0.1; 
Dacc = 1*10^(19 + 6); 
Nacc[μ_, T_, ϕ_, z_]=Dacc/(E^((ϵacc-μ)/(kb*T)-ϕ/(kb*T)) + 1); 
θD[z_] := (1 - Tanh[(1000/nm)*z])/2
ρD[ϕ_,z_,μ_]:=el*(-NcD[μ,Ta,ϕ]-Nacc[μ,Ta,ϕ,z]+PvD[μ, Ta, ϕ])*θD[z]; 
μexT = μ /. Quiet[FindRoot[ρT[μ, 0, 0]/el == 0, {μ, ϵcT}]][[1]]; 
μexD = μ /. Quiet[FindRoot[ρD[μ, 0, 0]/el == 0, {μ, ϵvD}]][[1]]; 
{μexT, μexD}

(*-----------------------------------------------------------*)
(*------------------SOLVING DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION------------*)
(*-----------------------------------------------------------*)

zleft = -1000 nm;
zright = 1000 nm;

poisson = D[D[ϕ[z],z],z] + (ρT[ϕ[z],z,μexT] + ρD[ϕ[z],z,μexD])/ϵ;
bc = {ϕ[zleft] == 0, ϕ'[zright] == 0};

ppR = 10000;
res = NDSolveValue[{poisson==0,bc}, ϕ, {z, zleft, zright},MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 10,AccuracyGoal -> 10,(*Method\[Rule]{"MethodOfLines",       "SpatialDiscretization"\[Rule]{"TensorProductGrid","MinPoints"\[Rule]ppR,"MaxPoints"\[Rule]ppR,"DifferenceOrder"\[Rule]2}}*)Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];

ϕa[z_] := res[z];
Ez[z_] := -D[ϕa[za], za] /. za -> z

a = Plot[{-ϕa[nm z]}, {z, zleft/nm, zright/nm},PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   FrameLabel -> {"z(nm)", "-e ϕ(eV)"},PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AspectRatio -> .75, PlotRange -> All,ImageSize -> Medium];

b = Plot[{ρT[ϕa[nm z],z, μexT]/(10^6 el), ρD[ϕa[nm z],z, μexD]/(10^6 el)}, {z,zleft/nm, zright/nm},PlotTheme -> "Scientific", FrameLabel -> {"z(nm)", "ρ(z)"}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AspectRatio -> .75, PlotRange -> All,ImageSize -> Medium];

c = Plot[{Ez[nm z]}, {z, zleft/nm, zright/nm},PlotTheme->"Scientific", FrameLabel -> {"z(nm)", "E(V/m)"},PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> "Expressions",AspectRatio -> .75, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium];

{a, b, c}


There are several methods to regularize Poisson equation with pure Neuman conditions - see this post  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191476/poisson-equation-with-pure-neumann-boundary-conditions/191518#191518
